# sending GET request to server and getting generated html page data from it in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, get

I've got some problems with sending request to server and getting generated html page data from it.
Example,I know the website like "http://www.xxxxxxxxxx.com" and I should send to it some parameters like "http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com?groupid=1100".
How can I do that? How to return full html page and how to return data from returned html page?
I mean for example

```
<body>
   <p>Today</p>
   <p>Today</p>
   <p>Tomorrow</p>
```

I need "Today Today Tomorrow" from that. Help me,please! Thank you for any help!!!!

Creating NSData

```
NSString *nameID = [[NSString alloc]initWithString: @"1"];        
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.xxxxx.com/news/index.php?id=%@", 
                       [nameID stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];

NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSData *urlData;
NSURLResponse *response;
urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:nil];
NSString *results = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
NSLog(@"%@",urlData);
```

I created NSData,but how to parse that?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`NSURLConnection`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for communication (sync and async possible: there are many tutorials out there). I would not use html as a response to a machine. I would use xml or json for this which can be parsed better by some [xml-parser](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project) or [json-parser](http://www.google.de/search?q=json+parser+iphone)

Comment: Thanks! but one more question.I created NSObject from request,but how to parse that? I added NSData creating to the first post.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean with NSObject: I cannot see one in your code. your edited code converts the received data into a string which you can feed into an xml- or json-parser.

Answer (score 0):

take the response data as NSData.You need to parse that Data .

Comment: Thanks! I created NSObject from request,but how to parse that? I added NSData creating to the first post.